# Visual Studio MVC URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I route to an address in MVC routing-config file, it works. But the URL in the bar doesn't update accordingly, it remains the same though contents are routed.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "User",                                         
    "Profile{id}",                          
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Details" }
);
```

It re-routes `localhost/profile4` to `localhost/home/details`, but the URL in the bar doesn't update.

Comment: Update to what? How are your creating your url? What do you expect it to display and what does it actually display.

Comment: bar(address bar where URL is shown) and i am not creating URL. i want to update URL in address bar to the URL i am routing to.

Comment: as i enter in address bar 
www.website.com/profile4
 when it route to my desired location i want to update its address in bar too, like it should look in address bar like
www.website.com/home/details

Comment: I think you want to use URL Rewrite instead: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: That's not what MVC *routing* does.  MVC routing takes a URL and routes to your controller+action.  It won't change the browser [address bar] because there's only a single request+response from the browser.  Sounds like you want to return an [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)  and provide the new URL in the response or use a javascript redirect.

Comment: yeah i know that not whats MVC routing does, but something like return URL attribute maybe able to update browser[address bar]

Comment: i want exactly what URL Rewrite [link](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) does but in MVC

Answer (score 0):

You can create two actions in your controller with two routes and make redirect.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "User",                                         
    "Profile{id}",                          
    new { controller = "Home", action = "ProfileRedirect" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Details",                                         
    "Details",                          
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Details" }
);

public class HomeController: Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ProfileRedirect(int id)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }
    }
```

Another solution is make some HttpHandler and redirect requests on global level.